# Detaching a started process

Tags: c++, qt

I've started a process using `QProcess::start()` and I need to detach it afterwards. How can I do it? I haven't found relevant info in the Qt docs.

I'm aware of `QProcess::startDetached()`, but due to other code in the program, I can't use it (I need to separate the starting and the detaching of the process).

Comment: I remember this being a feature request a couple of years ago, but I don't think it was ever implemented. Then again, I haven't kept up to date in recent times, so I might have missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't as of 5.1, [see here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9328). There's also a suggestion in the comments, not sure if useful for your case):

> Workaround proposal: write a helper process that starts detached processes, and terminates itself when all setting up is completed.

Answer (score 9):

If you take a look into [the implementation of `QProcess::~QProcess()`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp#n1226), you will know how `QProcess` terminates the process with its destruction. Also, note that [`QProcess::setProcessState()` is protected](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/io/qprocess.h#n255), which means you could implement a `QDetachableProcess` inherited from `QProcess` with a method `detach()` to call `setProcessState(QProcess::NotRunning);` as a workaround.

For example:

```
class QDetachableProcess : public QProcess
{
public:
    QDetachableProcess(QObject *parent = 0) : QProcess(parent){}
    void detach()
    {
        this->waitForStarted();
        setProcessState(QProcess::NotRunning);
    }
};
```

Then you could do things like this:

```
QDetachableProcess process;
process.setEnvironment(QStringList() << "SOME_ENV=Value");

process.start();

process.detach();
```

Comment: It would be better to include more of the answer in your answer rather than just linking.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Thanks. I've just added an example to make it clear.