# QProcess Set Environment Variables for startDetached

Tags: qt, qtcore, qprocess

I'm trying to figure out how to set environment variables to the startDetached function of QProcess in Linux. I did a google and found out that this is a [QT Bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-9328) and people have suggested workarounds on how to [start a detached process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501642/detaching-a-started-process) and I could see some code to override the startDetached function in Windows [set variables to detached qprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184986/change-path-environment-variable-for-cmd-exe-with-qprocessenvironment)

Could someone please post the code for how this needs to be done in Unix Systems. Thanks!!

Comment: Why use Qt for this task? Why not just C library execXX, spawnXX?

Comment: @user4419802 Thanks for your reply. I'm writing a Qt application and I've used QProcess start() function at a lot of places to start external applications. But for some reason startDetached() function does not take env variables and I need a workaround for this using QProcess itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As child process inherits the environment from the parent, I think that the easiest workaround is to save/modify/restore own environment using `qgetenv()` and `qputenv()` before and after `QProcess::startDetached()` call.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot. qputenv() did the needful for me. Thanks again.