# How to execute multiple QProcess in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ros, qprocess

I have been struggling on how to execute multiple processes using `QProcess`. I was able to execute a single process, e.i. opening a terminal window `QProcess *openTerminal = new QProcess(this);`, after that I wanted to execute additional processes but I could not find a way to do that. The order of operations I am trying to achieve are:

1) opening a gnome-terminal (this is solved and am able to open after `QPushButton` [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJPeX.png))

2) navigate to `cd ~`

3) Go to preferred directory `cd catkin_docking_ws/`

4) Launch proper application `roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch &`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    startLidar();
}

void MainWindow::startLidar()
{
    // Execution of the QProcess to make sure Lidar App Launcher opens:
    this->executeROSLidarApp = new QProcess(this);
    this->executeROSLidarApp->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
            [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] FINISHED: " << exitCode << exitStatus;
            if(script->bytesAvailable() > 0) qDebug() << "[EXEC] buffered DATA:" << script->readAll();
    });
    connect(this->executeROSLidarApp, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [script = this->executeROSLidarApp](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
            qDebug() << "[EXEC] error on execution: " << error << script->errorString();
    });
}


void MainWindow::on_launchLidarROSBtn_clicked()
{
    qDebug() << "Launching LIDAR APP";
    QProcess *openTerminal = new QProcess(this);
    QProcess *cd = new QProcess(this);
    QProcess *cd_catkin = new QProcess(this);
    QProcess *roslaunch = new QProcess(this);

    openTerminal->start("gnome-terminal");
    openTerminal->waitForFinished();

    cd->start("cd ~", QStringList() << "cd ~");
    cd->waitForFinished();

    cd_catkin->start("cd catkin_docking_ws/", QStringList() << "cd catkin_docking_ws/");
    cd_catkin->waitForFinished();

    roslaunch->start("roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch &", QStringList() << "roslaunch lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch &");
    roslaunch->waitForFinished();
}
```

I have conculted many sources in order to solve the problem such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701504/command-working-in-terminal-but-not-via-qprocess), I used also [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76873/write-to-macos-terminal-with-qprocess), [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82583/send-arguments-to-linux-terminal-with-qprocess). But all of them seems to give confusing information and am looking for a clean and simple process.

Also I dug more into the solution and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501642/detaching-a-started-process) advises to go for `detachedProcess` but I am not sure it is a good idea because [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701504/command-working-in-terminal-but-not-via-qprocess) seems to follow a pretty organized structure.

The end result I am trying to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGzKT.png) but, of course, passing through all the four `QProcess` I have above.

Is that possible or am I trying to handle too many processes altogether?
Thank you very much for pointing to the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: 1) Why is it necessary to execute several processes? 2) Those processes will be executed sequentially, ?, that is, process 2 will be executed after process 1 ends.

Comment: @eyllanesc, thanks for reading the question. To answer to your questions: 1) because that is the best idea I have in my mind now, but I am open for easier /quicker solutions, 2) "process 2 will be executed after process 1" ok, but what about the other processes?

Comment: Is that just the problem: I do not understand your basic objective since in your question you do not indicate it but you occupy your entire post in your *best idea*, why do not you use a single QProcess?, `QProcess process; ` in .h and add `process.start("roslaunch" {"~/catkin_docking_ws/lidar_deck lidar_deck_rosbag.launch"});`. Note: Each process is independent of the other, QProcess is not a terminal. Also Why is it necessary to use gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each QProcess represents a new session, so you cannot use multiple QProcess objects to execute a sequence. The best way would be to create a shell script that does what you want it to, then use one QProcess instance to execute that script.